# how to add edit link and how to display to another page using wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Iam new in wordpress . Im create a register form and insert into database table(test) then view the all register details in to another page. now iam give a edit link to all list of details. when iam click one its go to edit page and displayurl(http;//localhost.wordpress/edit/id=1) but page inside page not found.

```
<td><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/edit/id=<?php echo $id;?>">EDIT</a></td>
```

create edit.php page to theme folder and cutomize (dashboard) add new page edit(http://localhost/wordpress/edit) and select template (form edit)
how it solve?

Comment: edit page :
`<?php 
   require_once('wp-config.php'); 
   global $wpdb; 
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   $query = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = %d ", $id));?> `

Comment: <?php foreach ($results as $user)
       {
           $name= $user->test_name;
           $offer= $user->test_offer;
           $prize=$user->test_prize;
           $id=$user->id;
       }
       ?>
                   <tr> 
                       <td><?php echo $name;?></td> 
                       <td><?php echo $offer;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $prize;?></td>
                   </tr>